# When is it worth it to use the dual simplex method with warm starts?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Let's say I have a linear program that incurs a series of slight changes to it, so I want to warm-start it. I've read various things that recommend using the dual simplex algorithm over the primal depending on the nature of the change, e.g.

1. If the objective coefficients are changed or columns are added, warm start the primal.
2. If the RHS of the constraints is changed or a constraint is added, warm start the dual.

These guidelines essentially recommend solving the LP that maintains feasibility. I had a couple of concerns though:

1. Warm starts usually imply supplying a basis — will the corresponding dual basis simply be the variables not included in the primal basis?
2. Let's say the changes being made are mostly constraint RHSs changing. The criteria above would suggest to use the dual. Is this still the case if the number of constraints is small compared to the number of variables?